# Filter city cards based on select dropdown value on client side only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

```js
$(function() {
        $('#cityselector').change(function(){
            $('.city').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <Select id="cityselector">
                <option selected value="All">All</option>
                <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
                <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
                <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
            </Select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 city" id="Pune">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">

                    </div>  
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Pune- Koregaon Park</span>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 city" id="Pune">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">

                    </div>  
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Pune- Vimannagar</span>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 city" id="Chennai">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">

                    </div>  
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Chennai</span>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="col-md-4 city" id="Bengaluru">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">

                    </div>  
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Bengaluru</span>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I am building a new page called stores on shopify frontend. But, I am not going to use any database for that, I just wanted to filter or show/hide cards based on city selection from dropdown. I have already filter cities using jquery show hide.But it's not working when there are multiple cards with same city name. It's showing only one single city card using that. Also, I need to show all city cards, when user does select All option from dropdown. Kindly help me out with that.

Comment: Can you put your code in snippet?

Comment: I have already added it @RevtiShah

Comment: Please check Liad's Code.

Comment: But please check code, You gave same id name to pune. Which is wrong. IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insted of id, give class names:

```js
$(function() {
        $('#cityselector').change(function(){
            if($(this).val()=="All"){$('.city').show(); return;}else{$('.city').hide();}
            $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <Select id="cityselector">
                <option selected value="All">All</option>
                <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
                <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
                <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
            </Select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 city Pune" >
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">

                    </div>  
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Pune- Koregaon Park</span>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 city Pune" >
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">

                    </div>  
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Pune- Vimannagar</span>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 city Chennai" >
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">

                    </div>  
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Chennai</span>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="col-md-4 city Bengaluru" >
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">

                    </div>  
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Bengaluru</span>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: It also doesn;t work. When you select pune, it doesn;t show pune cities.

Comment: @RevtiShah, I think IDs should be unique while dealing with database, here we are just manipulating data and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for a value `All` to show all `.city` elements, just like this:

```
$(function() {
     $('#cityselector').change(function(){
          if($(this).val() == 'All')
              return $('.city').show();
          $('.city').hide();
          $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
     });
 });
```

EDIT:

I just noticed that it's not the only problem you had, to solve the same city's names problem, I would work with `classes` instead of working with `IDs`.

The reason this problem takes place, is because `jQuery` selectors by `ID` will always return one element, even if there are multiple elements with the same `ID`

Comment: It Works. Keep it up.

Comment: when you select pune, it shows only 1 option. But eventually it has already 2 options.

Comment: @RevtiShah Yes, because OP must work with classes and not with IDs,I explained why.